# How can I read this JSON file into Swift?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, mapbox

I'm trying to plot the following JSON file into the MapBox SDK by using the live feed SDK example.

Does anyone know how I could parse the flight number, longitude, latitude and aircraft type into Swift?

I've attached a link to the MapBox JSON file, the new JSON file, as well as an annotated snippet and the Swift code that is from the SDK.

Annotated snippet of the JSON file:

[image: Annotated snippet of the JSON file.]

https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?

https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/

```
import Mapbox

class LiveDataExample: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    var source: MGLShapeSource!
    var timer = Timer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a new map view using the Mapbox Dark style.
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds,
                                 styleURL: MGLStyle.darkStyleURL(withVersion: 9))
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.tintColor = .gray

        // Set the map view‘s delegate property.
        mapView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/") {
            // Add a source to the map. https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/ generates coordinates for simulated paths.
            source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "wanderdrone", url: url, options: nil)
            style.addSource(source)

            // Add a Maki icon to the map to represent the drone's coordinate. The specified icon is included in the Mapbox Dark style's sprite sheet. For more information about Maki icons, see https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/
            let droneLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "wanderdrone", source: source)
            droneLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "rocket-15")
            droneLayer.iconHaloColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white)
            style.addLayer(droneLayer)

            // Create a timer that calls the `updateUrl` function every 1.5 seconds.
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUrl), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func updateUrl() {
        // Update the icon's position by setting the `url` property on the source.
        source.url = source.url
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Invalidate the timer if the view will disappear.
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer()
    }
}
```

Comment: There are countless examples and tutorials about parsing JSON data in Swift. Please do some research and make an attempt. Then update your question showing what you tried and clearly explain what trouble you are having.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the message! The issue that i'm having is that non of the posts that always exist have the format of the JSON in a different format so i'm wondering if i'm looking at the wrong thing.